# ViewChild not find and bundle bigger when compile using AoT

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-compiler-cli

**ViewChild aren't find using AoT**

1. After get a *[3th party lib](https://github.com/swimlane/angular2-data-table)* support **AoT**, I succeed to compile with `ngc` no error on compilation!
2. I inject this *[3th party lib](https://github.com/swimlane/angular2-data-table)* into my project, so my project compile with CLI using `--aot` flag and no error during compilation, but when open app on navigator I get:

> ReferenceError: nameColumnHeader is not defined

3. This `nameColumnHeader` is a `ViewChild()` decorator :

`@ViewChild('nameColumnHeader') nameColumnHeader: TemplateRef<any>;`

Of course I have `<template #nameColumnHeader...>` inside HTML. When remove this ViewChild, another get me same issue #end of material2/sidenav component ...

I don't know what is problem and by the way, why cli don't tell me what is problem when **ng serve --prod --aot** on my project !!!

**Bundle main.js bigger using AoT**

I remove all my `ViewChild()` recompile with `--aot` all is OK, page shown correctly, but:
When I compile using `ng build --prod` the size of main.js is **1836 Ko** and when compile with AoT `ng build --prod --aot` the size of the main.js is : **1860Ko**

**IF USEFUL**

- [check my app.module.ts](http://pastebin.com/2MZ6B09C)
- [check my package.json](http://pastebin.com/h8bSQjPV)
- [check my tsconfig.json](http://pastebin.com/rm2JddCP)

## UPDATE:

When use ViewChild you need use semicolons !!! it's strange we can write ViewChild without seimicolons when compiling without AOT but with AoT you need semicolons

Comment: ViewChild is for when you only have one child. Otherwise, use ViewChildren. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, i have only ONE local variable with name `nameColumnHeader`. where you read I have many times `nameColumnHeader` as I can enhance my question?

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts

Comment: yes I did but this is semis problem